# XCode / Git, status of an updated file is no updated in source control

Tags: iphone, xcode, git

Guess I have an issue many may have had too. I am using a third party library. Naturally when the vendor publishes a new release I have to update the header files etc. in my project. But XCode does not come with a replace feature, so one has to Delete! the files and copy the new files into the project again. However, since I have done that, I have a header file, which keeps being in status A for added and a resource bundle (a directory with images and sound files from the SDK), which keeps telling me that it is not existing, when I want to commit the entire project.

Any idea, how I can clean up that mess? I submitted an enhance request to Apple as I find that replacing files in a project is a MUST feature.

Comment: ok, got the non-existing file issue resolved by adding 2 empty directories (which i am not able to delete now anymore, guess would have to add a file to them??)

Comment: - what is your output in the git project - terminal ==> git status
- sekcond: permisson issue try chmod
- I hope you have create a branch before you checked in the new lib.

Answer (score 1):

oh yeah the subversion problems … what I do as a last resort: delete the local files, pull the latest version and then apply the changes again. For me this issues often occur by adding or deleting folders. So I first add/delete the related files on the server (normally I use a third party app in that case, e.g. [gitbox](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gitbox/id403388357) or [SourceTree](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/sourcetree-git-hg/id411678673)) and then try syncing again.

Normally it should be possible to have multiple git repo's in one project (checkout the library into your project) but I personally don't like that. Instead I have the second repo in another directory and add those files as a linked reference (the option you can choose when adding new files -> uncheck `"copy items into destinations group folder"`). Whenever the library changes it will automatically apply to your project. The downside is that it will not automatically check if an update is available. On the other side it's probably safer to use an older library than a new one (every time you update the library you have theoretically test your whole application for bugs)

Back to your problem. In many cases it is easier to create a new repository structure. Backup the current state and delete the repo (local or remote). Then copy the files back to the repository and sync it. Should fix nearly all cases. (… and every time I try to solve it otherwise, I end up wasting hours with trying different methods to finally rebuild the whole repo like I described above -.-)

Comment: I do not recommend to delete the repo - try to remove the last commit. Good post from Chris for this subject: http://goo.gl/yCU2N

Tip: Anytime you make a import/update from third party product or major change. Create a new branch in your repo before you start.
- git branch myHotFix
- git checkout -b myHotFix
Now you can play and change anything - if is anything good - make a merge - if not drop the branch-->create a new and try again.

Comment: thx so far. For me it has naturalized while using SVN (no branches till than) but even with git I had some issues which I couldn't fix that way. Sometimes I get an unusable repo state so that I even can't establish a connection to the server. Maybe I said it ambiguous: I don't recommend to delete the repo, only as a last chance!

Comment: First of all sorry, for not replying earlier, Laptop was in the Apple hospital ;-) As for the answers:Holy moly, I JUST want to add a few files. The fact, that the answer is already 3 paragraphs (thanks relikd anyway) doesn't really add my confidence level for git. Professional tools (ok they cost a few hundreds / thousands US$) do not have any issues with replacing an existing file in the project and simply create a new version of it. And creating a branch, just because I would like to update a third party component? Hmmm, does not seem to be the right approach. Anyway, thanks again to all.